# How to find other solutions to this vectorproblem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Suppose I have a vector field $\mathbf{A}(x,y,z)$, of which I know:

$$ \mathbf{A}(x,y,0)=(1+\alpha x)\hat{z}$$
Thus, I know the value of $\mathbf{A}$ in the $xy$-plane. Say, within $|x|,|y|\leq\frac{1}{2}$.

Furthermore, I have the following requirements for $\mathbf{A}$.

$$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{A}=0, \\ \nabla\times\mathbf{A}=0,$$
which have to be satisfied in $|x|,|y|,|z|\leq{\frac{1}{2}}$.

I want to find the vector field $\mathbf{A}$ that satisfy all of the above conditions, at least for the given boundaries, but for larger (infinite?), domains as possible.

I did find the following solution, but, with some rather crude assumptions, so I wonder if there are any other approaches to solve the problem.

*Assumption 1:* There is no $y$-dependency.

*Assumption 2:* $\displaystyle\frac{d\mathbf{A}_x}{dx}=0$.

Under these assumptions, one can easily obtain from the curl-requirement, that

$$\mathbf{A}=\alpha z\hat{x}+(1+\alpha x)\hat{z}$$

But, is this the only one? I am especially interested in other solutions which do no show $y$-dependency, and, even more interested if there is a solution $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to\infty}\mathbf{A}_x<\infty$. A proof that the solution that I obtained straightforwardly is the only one obviously also counts as an answer.

Comment: Please feel free to retags/retitle, I do not know my way around here yet.

Comment: Not a full solution, but notice that if $A$ is curl-free over a simply connected region, it must be the gradient of some potential $u$, and that if furthermore $A$ is divergence-free, that $u$ is harmonic. So you are looking for harmonic functions over the ball satisfying some rather strong conditions along the $xy$ plane.

Comment: @user7530 I got that, so basically, is know at the plane, and also the derivative of $A_x$, but then?

Comment: You know that $u$ is constant (and so WLOG, zero) on the plane, and you also have Neumann conditions on $u$ along the plane. Maybe you can show uniqueness from this.

Comment: @user7530 What do you mean with WLOG? And what do you mean with constant for $u$? It can look like $1+x+z+xz$?

Comment: On the $xy$ plane, $A = \nabla u$ is orthogonal to the plane. This means $u$ must be constant along the plane.

Comment: Then since $\nabla (u+c) = \nabla u$, adding constants to $u$ doesn't change $A$ and you might as well take $u=0$ on the $xy$ plane.

Comment: @user7530 I do understand what you mean and it make sense. But, this does not give me different solutions for $A$ yet. Does it somehow prove that there is no other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solution is unique.

Suppose there existed two vector fields $A=\nabla u$ and $B=\nabla v$ satisfying your conditions. Then $A-B = \nabla(u-v)$ where $w=u-v$

1. is harmonic;
2. is constant on the $xy$ plane;
3. satisfies $\partial_z w = 0$ on the $xy$ plane.

Pick a point on the $xy$ plane, e.g. the origin. At that point,
$$\partial_x^a \partial_y^b w = 0$$
for any $a,b$ since $w$ is constant on the plane. Moreover
$$\partial_x^a \partial_y^b \partial_z w = 0$$
by property (3). Since $w$ is harmonic, 
$$\partial_x^a\partial_y^b\partial_z^{c+2} w= -\partial_x^{a+2}\partial_y^b\partial_z^c w - \partial_x^a\partial_y^{b+2}\partial_z^c w$$
and it follows that *all* partial derivatives of $w$ at the point vanish, and so since harmonic functions are analytic, $w$ is constant.

Therefore $A-B=0$ and $A$ is unique.

Comment: Thank you. I am not familiar with the notation $\partial_x^a$. (I do understand $\partial_x$ is the derivative wrt $x$). Can you please explain?

Comment: @Bernhard I just mean $\frac{\partial^a}{\partial x^a}$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\vec{A} = \vec{\nabla} \phi$, where $\phi$ is a harmonic function. In addition, we want $$\vec{A} \cdot \vec{e}_z = (1+ax) + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_k(x,y) z^k \text{ i.e., }
\phi(x,y,z) = f(x,y) + (1+ax)z + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} g_k(x,y) z^k$$
Here is one possibility that gives rise to a large class of candidates:
Let $$\vec{A} = \vec{\nabla}\left(\psi(x,y) + (1+ax)z \right)$$ where $\psi(x,y)$ is any $2$D harmonic functions.

Comment: Thank you. If I use the harmonic function $\psi(x,y)=\exp(x)\sin(y)$, than I find in the $xy$-plane for the $y$ component of $A_y=\exp(x)\cos(y)$, which does not match my first requirement? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Bernhard What is your first requirement? As I see you only have three requirement, $\vec{A}$ is divergence free, curl free and $\vec{A}(x,y,0) = (1+ax) \hat{e}_z$.

Comment: The last statement in your comment says that $A\cdot x=0$ and $A \cdot y=0$. This was my first equation (or constraint)

Comment: @Bernhard Oh Ok. For some reason, I read it as $\vec{A}(x,y,0).\vec{e}_z = (1+ax)$.